# MongoMapper weird result

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I just started workin with MongoMapper and even though I've followed the "guide" on mongomapper.com, I still get unexpected results when querying a database.  Here is the result:

```
#<User:0x000000028d5070>
#<User:0x000000028d45a8>
#<User:0x000000029ec148>
#<User:0x000000029eb928>
```

My code:

```
require "mongo_mapper"
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017)
MongoMapper.database = "mydb"

class User
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String
  key :age,  Integer

  many :hobbies
end


class Hobby
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument

  key :name,    String
  key :started, Time
end


user = User.new(:name => 'Brandon')
user.hobbies.build(:name => 'Programming',
  :started => 10.years.ago)

user.save!

puts User.where(:name => 'Brandon').all
```

I have tried using various things like .first after the .where part and I still get the same results, or, a Plucky::Query object.

Comment: Unexpected, because you only want to see one result instead of many? Is the problem that you create another document every time you run this code?

Answer (score 1):

The line should have been:

```
puts User.where(:name => 'Brandon').first.name
```